# convert string array to integer php

Tags: php, string, integer

**Question:**
How the best to convert `$p=' "'.implode('","', $person).'"';`    `$p` to an integer?

**What I have:**
I am trying to use an if statement telling `$person == false;`

`$x['date'];` is the timestamp in my database.
I have worked out the time difference, now I am trying to make the person disappear if post over 3 seconds. 
so I used `$t > 3` seconds then the `$p ==  false;`
The difficulty for my was the `$t` was implode so it a single string. I was trying to use preg_match, but I don't think this is a good idea.
I am trying to use `$difference = settype($t, "integer");` but I am getting a boolean rather than a number.

```
$diff = array();
$person = array();
foreach($stmt as $x)
{  
 $person[] =   $x['names']. $x['ages'];

$posts[] = $x['date'];
$timePosted = new DateTime($posts[] = $x['date']);
echo 'Time Posted : '. $timePosted ->format("d-m-Y H:i:s");
echo "</br>";

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
$today = date('d-m-Y H:i:s');
echo 'Current time is : '. $today;
echo "</br>"; 

$today = new DateTime(date('d-m-Y H:i:s'));
$interval = $timePosted->diff($today);
"Difference " . $interval->d. " days ". $interval->h. " hours ".$interval->i." minutes ".$interval->s." seconds ";
echo "</br>";

$diff[] = $interval->h. " hours ".$interval->i." minutes ".$interval->s." seconds ";
$diff[] = $interval->s;  //last array seconds
}
$p=' "'.implode('","', $person).'"';      
echo $t= ' "'.implode('","', $diff).'"'."<br />";
$difference = settype($t, "integer");
echo gettype($difference);
echo "</br>";



if( $t >3){
  $p == false;
}else{
 echo "its okay, smaller than 3 seconds";
}
```

Comment: its a very long question, and not easy to grasp what you are saying at first, but I saw you asking "convert $p to an integer?", maybe `$p = intval($p)`, converts it to a proper integer? IF not, can you make your question shorter and concise.

Comment: And what is the value of `$t`?

Comment: @MuhammedM. yes, you are right. sorry about the question, I was trying to explain what I have before asking question, I will try to edit the question. thanks

Comment: @u_mulder t is all user posts time difference(seconds) from the time they post and now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're setting `$difference = settype($t, "integer");`

The `settype` function returns a boolean. The value `$t` should be set to an integer, so to test, use `echo gettype($t);` instead of `echo gettype($difference);`

also, you're using a comparison operator instead of the assignment in

```
if( $t >3){
  $p == false;
```

it should be

```
if( $t >3){
  $p = false;
```

Comment: he is actually right, if you are doing settype do this `settype($t, "integer");` instead of this: `$difference = settype($t, "integer");`